# Android Studio, problem with compatibility ? (Android > 10)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compatibility

New day, new problem..

I'll try to explain my problem clearly.

I tested my application on Android 10 (API 29) and everything works fine.

I'm testing the **same app on Android 13 (API 33)** and I have problems transitioning between the different pages of my app.

My app launches fine, I manage to log in (there's a login system) and I arrive on "Home".

When I click to navigate in my app, it crashes.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo (...) 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Integer fr.xxx.yyy.models.Configuration.Societe.getIdSociete()' on a null object reference
```

The problem line :

```
String IdSociete = AppConfig.getInstance().company.getIdSociete().toString();
```

To explain, after a user logs in, I retrieve json information, including some about the company, which I store in a model.

After log in, I display the **IdSociete** value directly to make sure it's actually stored.

In this place (after the log in) : It is !

My question is : Why is it that when I want to retrieve the same value in the same way, in another place in the code, it can't find the reference ?

Why do I only have this problem on Android versions > 10 ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Has anyone ever had this problem ? :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i solved my problem !

My code before :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

The FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT was the problem with Android 12+

I solved my problem like this :

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
     mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
}
else{
     mGeofencePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```